# Resiliently processing messages from RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm not sure how to resiliently handle RabbitMQ messages in the event of an intermittent outage.

I subscribe in a windows service, read the message, then store it my database.  If I can't process the record because of the data I publish it to a dead letter queue for a human to address and reprocess.

I am not sure what to do if I have some intermittent technical issue that will fix itself (database reboot, network outage, drive space, etc).  I don't want hundreds of messages showing up on dead letter that just needed to wait for a for a glitch but now would be waiting on a human.

Currently, I re-queue the event and retry it once, but it retries so fast the issue is not usually resolved.  I thought of retrying forever but I don't want a *real* issue to get stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Is a broad topic but from  the server side you could persist your messages and make your queues durable, this means that in the eventuality the server gets restarted they won't be lost, check more here  [How to persist messages during RabbitMQ broker restart?](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2017-03-14-how-to-persist-messages-during-RabbitMQ-broker-restart.html)

For the consumer (client) it will depend on how you configure your client, from the docs:

> In the event of network failure (or a node crashing), messages can be duplicated, and consumers must be prepared to handle them. If possible, the simplest way to handle this is to ensure that your consumers handle messages in an idempotent way rather than explicitly deal with deduplication.
>
> If a message is delivered to a consumer and then requeued (because it was not acknowledged before the consumer connection dropped, for example) then RabbitMQ will set the redelivered flag on it when it is delivered again (whether to the same consumer or a different one). This is a hint that a consumer may have seen this message before (although that's not guaranteed, the message may have made it out of the broker but not into a consumer before the connection dropped). Conversely if the redelivered flag is not set then it is guaranteed that the message has not been seen before. Therefore if a consumer finds it more expensive to deduplicate messages or process them in an idempotent manner, it can do this only for messages with the redelivered flag set.

Check more here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html#consumer